# Read data from an `InputStream`

Tags: java, scala, io, inputstream

**Disclaimer**: I work on a non-traditional project, so don't be shocked if some assumptions seem absurd.

## Context

I wish to create a stream reader for integers, strings, and the other common types in Scala, but to start with I focus only on integers. Also note that I'm not interesting in handling exception at the moment -- I'll deal with them in due time and this will be reflected in the API and in the meantime I can make the huge assumption that failures won't occur..

The API should be relatively simple, but due to the nature of the project I'm working on, I can't rely on some feature of Scala and the API needs to look something like this (slightly simplified for the purpose of this question):

```
object FileInputStream {
  def open(filename: String): FileInputStream =
    new FileInputStream(
      try {
        // Check whether the stream can be opened or not
        val out = new java.io.FileReader(filename)
        out.close()
        Some[String](filename)
      } catch {
        case _: Throwable => None[String]
      }
    )
}

case class FileInputStream(var filename: Option[String]) {
  def close: Boolean = {
    filename = None[String]
    true // This implementation never fails
  }

  def isOpen: Boolean = filename.isDefined

  def readInt: Int = nativeReadInt

  private def nativeReadInt: Int = {
    ??? // TODO
  }
}

object StdIn {
  def readInt: Int = nativeReadInt

  private def nativeReadInt: Int = {
    ??? // TODO
  }
}
```

Please also note that I cannot rely on additional fields in this class, with the exception of `Int` variables. This (probably) implies that the stream has to be opened and closed for every operations. Hence, it goes without saying that the implementation will not be efficient, but this is not an issue.

## The Question

My goal is to implement the two `nativeReadInt` methods such that the input stream gets consumed by only one integer if one is available straight away. However, if the input doesn't start (w.r.t. the last read operation) with an integer then nothing should be read and a fixed value can be returned, say `-1`.

I've explored several high level Java and Scala standard APIs, but none seemed to offer a way to re-open a stream to a given position trivially. My hope is to avoid implementing low level parsing based solely on `java.io.InputStream` and its `read()` and `skip(n)` methods.

Additionally, to let the user read from the standard input stream, I need to avoid using `scala.io.StdIn.readInt()` method because it reads "an entire line of the default input", therefore trashing some potential data.

Are you aware of a Java or Scala API that could do the trick here?

Thank you

Comment: This is too "non-traditional". You should start with re-examining your "assumptions", because I am willing to bet my launch that most of them are simply wrong. Rather than listing the "assumptions" you made, try explaining what it is you are _actually trying to do_. Chances are someone will suggest a solution, that would not involve things like opening and closing files to check that they exist.

Comment: @Dima "try explaining what it is you are actually trying to do": this I did. I didn't cover the assumptions (which are more constraints, actually) above because it's already lengthy and they were discussed by several clever people in the past. The headline is that I'm working on some sort of automatic conversion from Scala to C in Leon and I want to support I/O's. But we can abstract from this complex context to solve this problem, fortunately. ;-)

Comment: It is indeed long. But "long" and "informative" isn't the same. Instead of explaining _what_ you need  to do, you describe _how_ you are trying to do it, and your _how_ is _all wrong_.  Rather than listing your "assumptions", you have to explain the _basis_ for them. For example, you are saying "I cannot rely on additional variables". This does not make any sense. You, probably, made this conclusion based on some requirement you are trying to satisfy. The requirement may be true, but your conclusion most certainly is not.

Comment: @Dima Please read the disclaimer again. I know it's shocking and I get why you seem this to make no sense, but I genuinely cannot add variables of "complex" type as **fields** (such as Scala or Java classes) -- this is a current limitation of the tool I'm working on. For example, the `Option` you see above is not `scala.Option` but something else that the tool is supporting. If I were to explain every single details here, I would end up with no-one reading the question at all, except the people I'm working with and this is obviously no the goal. That's why I made a few white lies above.

Comment: You'll end up with no-one reading the question at all as it is, because it doesn't make any sense.